# Problems with Django Websockets

Tags: python, django, deployment, backend, django-channels

I followed a Django Websockets tutorial in which I created a chatroom website. It didn't work so I doubble checked the code and I did everything the same as in the tutorial. I decided to clone the repository and check what is the problem with my code. I realized that the websockets didn't work with the downloaded project as well. Is there something wrong with the code or my computer?

Link to the Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsxFEONN_yo

Link to the repo: https://github.com/veryacademy/YT-Django-Project-Chatroom-Getting-Started.git

I created a virtual env and installed django and channels. The only change I made is in the settings.py file where I replaced

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [os.environ['REDIS_URL']],
        },
    },
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
        }
    }
}
```

With:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need redis. Please check below doc.

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html

In-memory channel layers operate with each process as a separate layer. This means that no cross-process messaging is possible. As the core value of channel layers is to provide distributed messaging, in-memory usage will result in sub-optimal performance, and ultimately data-loss in a multi-instance environment.

This means you can not use In-memory to cross-process messaging, which i guess tutorial you are following !

Comment: I was doing some searching and looked at thee link you gave me. I installed channels-redis and django-redis and I reverted the changes in the settings.py file to the ones mentioned in my post. I replaced the first "REDIS_URL" with ("localhost", 6379) and the other with "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1" but i still get the same problem that the socket connection failed and a GET /ws/chat/adw/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2216 response from the server. Do you have any ideas of what can be the problem?